# Android how to get the width of actionbar

Tags: java, android

I need to get the width of the action bar I've seen loads of stuff to get the height, but not the width? can anyone help? See below for code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11.0){
                            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
                            ((Activity) context).getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                                    new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
                            ((Activity) context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
                            actionBarWidth = ((Activity) context).getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
                        }
```

Comment: is it not width of the screen?

Comment: As in the collasped menu button in the header?

Comment: I need to take into account the width of the collasped menu botton in the action bar to scale a title correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LayoutParams. Layout params allows you to get and set the Layout related parameters such as Height, Width etc for any View inherited object.

Comment: So how would I do that with a collapsed menu bar in the actionbar (e.g. on a nexus 5)